# Couldn't find ExtensionPackage without an ID - Adobe-Launch API

Tags: adobe, adobe-launch

Calling `reactor.reviseExtension()` from Adobe's `reactor-sdk-javascript` is returning this:

```sh
FetchError: 409 Conflict ('Couldn't find ExtensionPackage without an ID') on POST https://reactor.adobe.io/properties/******************************/extensions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying error here is likely due to one of two issues. Prior to making the `reviseExtension` call, you’ll want to make sure your `POST` body for `Extension` supplies a relationship to an `ExtensionPackage`. That `ExtensionPackage` must exist and be available for use on the `Property`.

Ref: https://developer.adobelaunch.com/api/reference/1.0/extensions/create/